# convert one row into columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is my query. That show me results as described in the screen shot. Now i want to change it so it show me statues of the month in columns.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
MonthName           VARCHAR(10),
[Year]              VARCHAR(10),
StatusTypeId        INT,
StatusTypeName      VARCHAR(50),
StatusCount         INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT
CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)) as MonthName,
datepart(yyyy, w.ExpectedStartDate) as [Year],
w.StatusTypeId,
st.StatusTypeName,
COUNT(ISNULL(w.StatusTypeId, 0)) AS StatusCount
FROM
Worksheet w LEFT OUTER JOIN
StatusType st ON st.StatusTypeId = w.StatusTypeId
WHERE   w.ProjectId = 20
AND CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)) between ('feb') AND    ('mar')
GROUP BY
datepart(yyyy, w.ExpectedStartDate),
CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)),
w.StatusTypeId,
st.StatusTypeName

SELECT  ISNULL(((CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [Year])) + '-' + MonthName), 'Unknown') AS     MonthName,
    ISNULL(StatusTypeName, 'Unknown') AS StatusTypeName,
    StatusCount
FROM @temp
```

I think this image will describe well what i need.

[image]

Please let me know how can i sort it by month name.. eg. Jan, feb, mar, jun, dec. etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out pivot tables;

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

A simple query for a finite number of StatusTypeNames would be something like like;

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT MonthName, StatusTypeName as attributeCol, StatusCount FROM @ResultsTable) rt 
PIVOT ( MAX(StatusCount) FOR attributeCol in ([ToBeScheduled],[Complete])) as pvt
ORDER BY MonthName
```

Note the use of MAX. If there is chance you'll have multiple rows with the same monthname and status typename combination, then you might want to use SUM.

To make use of dynamic columns as madhivinan suggests, you can follow [this example.](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx) Scroll to the bottom.

I tried to get it to work with your example, but because I had a couple of issues probably due to the fact I didn't have the tables. However, something like the following is what you are after.

```
DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT  @listCol = SELECT STUFF (( SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + 
                    StatusTypeName FROM @ResultsTable ORDER BY '],[' + 
                    StatusTypeName FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'


SET @query =
'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT MonthNameCol, StatusTypeName as attributeCol, StatusCount FROM @ResultsTable) rt
PIVOT ( MAX(StatusCount) FOR attributeCol in ('+@listCol+')) AS pvt ORDER BY MonthNameCol'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

It's not exactly right, but it's a starting point.

Good luck.

Comment: I have seen this but i am confuse that how to convert row into columns when when don't know that how much rows will be return and what are the records of rows. I means dynamically converting rows to columns without knowing what is the data in row.

Comment: Hi, I am unable to get required results using PIVOT. :(

Comment: You will @Sami. I just tried with a simple example and it works OK. Try again with my updated edit.

Comment: @Moose: This is my query but it gives me error
*Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'MonthName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'StatusCount'.*

I am adding query in next comment. i am unable to post it here.

Comment: DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT  @listCol = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
'],[' + st.StatusTypeName
FROM    Worksheet w LEFT OUTER JOIN
StatusType st ON st.StatusTypeId = w.StatusTypeId
ORDER BY '],[' + st.StatusTypeName
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @query =
'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT w.MonthName, StatusTypeName as attributeCol, StatusCount FROM 
Worksheet w LEFT OUTER JOIN
    StatusType st ON st.StatusTypeId = w.StatusTypeId
) rt
PIVOT ( MAX(StatusCount) FOR attributeCol in ('+@listCol+')) AS pvt ORDER BY MonthName'
EXECUTE (@query)

Comment: sorry it was my mistake i have given wrong column names. sorry

Comment: No probs. Glad it was of some use. 

I had some performance problems on some of my queries like this. After days of searching, and pouring over query plans, I came across something useful. 

When checking queries that ran fast against queries that hung, it was queries that performed a loop join worked OK, whereas queries that performed a hash join would sometimes hang until timeout. Therefore, I added the following query hint after the ORDER BY clause so you end up with;
ORDER BY MonthName option (loop join, order group).
 
I wouldn't suggest query hints unless you are facing issues though.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of dynamic PIVOT approach shown in this post
http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2008/08/27/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server-2005.aspx