# how to use PIVOT to get required results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert one row into columns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421437/convert-one-row-into-columns)

This is my query.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
MonthName           VARCHAR(10),
[Year]              VARCHAR(10),
StatusTypeId        INT,
StatusTypeName      VARCHAR(50),
StatusCount         INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT
CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)) as MonthName,
datepart(yyyy, w.ExpectedStartDate) as [Year],
w.StatusTypeId,
st.StatusTypeName,
COUNT(ISNULL(w.StatusTypeId, 0)) AS StatusCount
FROM
Worksheet w LEFT OUTER JOIN
StatusType st ON st.StatusTypeId = w.StatusTypeId
WHERE   w.ProjectId = 20
AND CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)) between ('feb') AND     ('mar')
GROUP BY
datepart(yyyy, w.ExpectedStartDate),
CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)),
w.StatusTypeId,
st.StatusTypeName

SELECT  ISNULL(((CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [Year])) + '-' + MonthName), 'Unknown') AS        MonthName,
ISNULL(StatusTypeName, 'Unknown') AS StatusTypeName,
StatusCount
FROM @temp
```

I want result like this.[image]

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eg.

```
select
  *
from
(
  select
    monthname,statustypename
  from yourtable
) DataTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(statuscount)
  FOR statustypename
  IN ( 
    [tobescheduled],[complete]
  )
) PivotTable
```

Also check the link 
http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/08/04/87166.aspx